# Run unit tests project with continues integration in multiple environments?

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, app-config, tfs-2015

I created a unit test project and added it to the build definitions.

We have **Staging** env and **Production** env and the unit test run tests on our api and I would like it to test in those environments, but for each env I need to replace the api address.
 for **staging**: **http://mycompany_staging/api/GetEmployees** and 
for **production** **http://mycompany_production/api/GetEmployees**

For our other web projects we used **web.config transform**, but for the unit test project it doesn't work because there is a problem with the transformation of it's app.config.
 I tried using **SlowCheetah** to transform the app.config, but with not much of success.

I am sure there is some kind of out of the box solution from **Microsoft**, right?

Comment: Have a try with this extension [Configuration Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) in marketplace?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a task step in every environment to update the app.config file. Tasks you can use: [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)  or [Tokenization Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TotalALM.totalalm-tokenization).